# insert a single value into new created column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

First of all: It sounds pretty basic to me, but i did not find anything on this topic that comes close.

I am using pl-sql and have a table thats contains records. Now i have created a new column and want to insert an entry when specific conditions given. Something like this

```
insert into myTable (newColumn)
values (newValue)
where oldColumn = 'something';
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

Is this 
possible with an `insert` statement or do i have to undo the whole row and rewrite it with the old values and the new one?

Thanks, newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
updatE myTable
    set newColumn = newValue
    where oldColumn = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use update query instead of insert as your table is ready with records and you have added a new column to existing table that is having values in it.

syntax is as follows:

```
UPDATE new_column_name
SET new_column_name='Dummy value' where (condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add values to a new column. But its corresponding row is already there. So you need to update the row, not insert. You can do like,

```
updatE myTable
set newColumn = newValue
where oldColumn = 'something';
```